# How to add index terms manually in apache solr

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

I want to add a documents information in solr so that I can search it for a case. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file post.sh (or post.jar) in `example/exampledoc` in solr. Your document should be in xml, csv,json formats that you want to index.then run the following command to index data in solr.

```
./post.sh myfile.xml
```

you can also use post.jar. For further help, consult [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Simple+Post+Tool)

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to add documents to a Solr core is using the administration console:**

1. open the Solr administration console at `http://solr-host:port/solr/`
2. select a core from the "*Core selector*" dropdown menu
3. click on "*Documents*" to add documents in the format you need (XML, JSON, etc)
4. click on "*Submit Document*" to add your document to the core.
5. Then you can see all the documents using "*Query*" menu.

[image: Solr add and update documents using admin console]

Comment: How to import indexes from solr to local files system

Comment: Is it a question? Is this related to this answer?
Please, if it's a question, first do your search and then post another question.

Comment: Please answer following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597504/how-to-reindex-data-in-solr-that-is-crawled-by-nutch-and-saved-in-hbases-tables